# List comprehension of 3 nested loops and the output is based on if-else condition

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

Is it possible to convert this into a list comprehension? For example, I have a list v. On the source code below, v = dictionary.keys()

```
v = ["naive", "bayes", "classifier"]
```

I have the following nested list t.

```
t = [["naive", "bayes"], ["lol"]]
```

The expected output O should be:

```
O = [[1 1 0], [0 0 0]]
```

1 if the dictionary contains the word and 0 if not.  I'm creating a spam/ham feature matrix.  Due to the large dataset, I'd like to convert the code below into a list comprehension for a faster iteration.

```
ham_feature_matrix = []
for each_file in train_ham:
    feature_vector = [0] * len(dictionary)
    for each_word in each_file:
        for d,dicword in enumerate(dictionary.keys()):
            if each_word == dicword:
                feature_vector[d] = 1
    ham_feature_matrix.append(feature_vector)
```

Comment: `v` is not a dictionary. it's a _list_

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't test this, but this translates as:

```
ham_feature_matrix = [[[int(each_word == dicword) for dicword in dictionary] for each_word in each_file] for each_file in train_ham]
```

`[int(each_word == dicword) for dicword in dictionary]` is the part which changes the most compared to your original code.

Basically, since you're iterating on the words of the dictionary, you don't need `enumerate` to set the matching slots to `1`. The comprehension builds the list with the result of the comparison which is `0` or `1` when converted to integers. You don't need to get the keys since iterating on a dictionary iterates on the keys by default.

The rest of the loops is trivial.

The issue I'm seeing here is that you're iterating on a dictionary to create a list of booleans, but the order of the dictionary isn't fixed, so you'll have different results each time (like in your original code) unless you sort the items somehow.

Comment: Sorry. I should have specified that v refers to dictionary.keys().